# Given $P[S|A\cap B]$ and $P[S|A\cap B']$ can we find P[S|A]?

Tags: probability

Is there a theorem to or formula to solve the above probability question?

Here are the specifics:

$P[S]=0.36$

$P[A\cap B]=0.56$

$P[A\cap B']=0.21$

$P[S|A\cap B]=0.6$

$P[S|A\cap B']=0.45$

$P[S|A] = ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  By the Law of Total Probability.

$\begin{align}\mathsf P[S\mid A]&=\mathsf P[S\mid A\cap B]~\mathsf P[B\mid A]+\mathsf P[S\mid A\cap B']~\mathsf P[B'\mid A]\\[2ex]&=\phantom{\dfrac{\mathsf P[S\mid A\cap B]~\mathsf P[A\cap B]+\mathsf P[S\mid A\cap B']~\mathsf P[A\cap B']}{\mathsf P[A\cap B]+\mathsf P[A\cap B']}}\end{align}$